# Server.Transfer throws Error executing child request. How to resolve?

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0, server.transfer

I have a `HttpModule` in C# 2.0 which handles exceptions thrown. Whenever the exception is thrown, an error page (aspx) with some querystring will be called. It is done through `Server.Transfer()`.

But when the control tries to execute `Server.Transfer()`, the following exception is thrown:

> Error executing child request for [pagename].aspx.

Whereas `Request.Redirect()` works fine.

I tried setting `EnableViewStateMac="false"` in Page directive of the page to which request is transferred. Still problem persists.

Here is the code I tried:

```cs
string errorPage = "errorpage.aspx?id=" + someErrorId
HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(errorPage,true);
```

Any idea how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found an alternative to Server.Transfer()

I used

```cs
 HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("somefile.aspx");
```

This solved the issue.

Comment: How did you use it? The exception *Error executing child request* disappeared, but I get an empty page.

Comment: You have to do it in a IHttpModule.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx (unfortunately the article is way overlong, the actual concept is pretty simple).

Comment: If you have `Server.Transfer` available to you, you can probably just call `Context.RewritePath`, rather than needing to call `HttpContext.Current` to get an HttpContext object :)

Answer (score 16):

I was hooking into the request pipeline in the **OnPreRequestHandlerExecute** event, and found I couldn't use Server.Transfer because it threw the same error as yours about executing a child request.

Using HttpContext.Current.RewritePath didn't work because it seemed to be ignored and I wasn't redirected anywhere.

If you're using IIS 7 and up, you can use **Server.TransferRequest** instead which did the trick for me.

The differences between the two methods are covered in this answer: [TransferRequest vs Transfer in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002551/transferrequest-vs-transfer-in-asp-net)

Comment: Worked for me. Other answers didn't.

Answer (score 8):

My fix was different:

An online query produced [this Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320439) which stated the resolution would be to use **Response.Redirect** instead of **Server.Transfer**.

I changed the command and got a more accurate "*404 Error Message*" instead of the cryptic "*Error executing child request*" message.

That led me to inspect the redirect string and I noticed my path was off.

I fixed the Transfer String from "ErrorPage.aspx" to "../ErrorPage.aspx" (notice the path change) and **Server.Transfer** worked just fine.

Comment: I found that I needed to change this to "~/ErrorPage.aspx", or else it would stop working when I moved from a sub-directory up to the application root (see my answer)

Comment: We were using Server.Execute and got the message.  Thanks! It was also a 404 Error.

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to see this exception occur in the VS.NET IDE during debug, go ahead at least once and press F5 to continue debugging. In my case, the actual page did render with the ASP.NET exception that was *really* causing the issue. In my case I had an incorrectly formatted `asp:ChangePassword` control that was *actually* causing the "Error executing child request" exception.

Comment: I believe this is also exposed in the `InnerException` property of the exception.  In my case it was a missing user control.

Answer (score 2):

I changed **Server.Transfer** for **Server.TransferRequest**, then I've got the real exception behind. It was a problem with a reference to an incorrect ReportViewer version.

Answer (score 0):

**Server.Transfer("mywebpage.aspx")** seems to work only when a session already exists.

If there is no Session started it throws this error so you must use **Response.Redirect** or another method.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and discovered it was to do with the relative paths of where the Server.Transfer is running and where you are redirecting to. In my case, this was executing in a sub-directory, so @ray's answer (adding ../ to the start of the URL) worked. However, when I then executed in the directory above, the same thing happened. Therefore, I changed to using a rooted path:

```
Server.Transfer("~/errorpage.aspx")
```

Answer (score -1):

It isn't a bug, it is by design. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320439

Comment: Yes I had seen that. But I had a requirement not change the URL on the address bar.

Comment: He isn't redirecting to ASP

Comment: It happens whereever you redirect.

Comment: It is only "by design" for a specific use case in the linked article