# How can I execute a virtual path inside a HTTP module?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I'm trying to execute a virtual path inside a HTTP module (I want to capture the result).

But I get an error:

> Error executing child request for /home/something/.

Code:

```
public void ExecuteUrl(string url)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(url, sw);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361690/server-transfer-throws-error-executing-child-request-how-to-resolve) says that it's by design, and the accepted answer won't work for me since I want to capture the result.

Is there another approach that I can take?

Comment: Is this MVC or vanilla ASP.NET ?

Comment: If possible I would like ASP.NET to run the URI through all modules/handler to find one which can handle the URI.

Comment: Maybe I just don't get something.. but why not to use WebClient's Download with your URI?

Comment: @Lanorkin: Since it will be less efficient than executing everything in process.