# How to fix Error executing child request?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am building an asp.net app and I keep getting this error while trying to transfer pages:

> Error executing child request for Edit_PropertyData.aspx

I have no clue what's causing it or how to fix it, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the `Page_Load` event of `Edit_PropertyData.aspx`

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cmdChangeMaterial.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckSaveStatus();")
    cmdEditMaterial.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckSaveStatus();")

    If Session("Mode") Is "Edit" Then
        cmdEditMaterial.Enabled = True
        cmdSaveData.Enabled = True
    Else
        cmdEditMaterial.Enabled = False
        cmdSaveData.Enabled = False
    End If

    pnlMain.Visible = True
    pnlMain.Height = Unit.Pixel(650)

End Sub
```

Comment: Share your code of Edit_PropertyData.aspx

Comment: @ClarkKent just the `Page_Load` event?

Comment: `Server.Transfer` is very limited. Why do you need it? Wouldn't e.g. `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` work better? Or perhaps you should use an even better approach?

Comment: @Luaan hmmm, I'll try `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` I've never used that before

Comment: More importantly, why are you doing `Server.Transfer` in the first place? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Server.Transfer` doesn't allow you to do a lot of things. You're probably trying to use it to pass query string parameters or some such. But you don't need that - the URL doesn't change in the target of the transfer, so you've still got the original query string. This can be both a good and a bad thing, depending on how you use it :)

You probably want to use a different transfer method instead - if you're inside a `HttpModule`, have a look at `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath`.

Comment: I tried the `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` and another error came up. I'm just trying to make it so when the user clicks a button a different web page comes  up

Comment: @bbesase That's what `Response.Redirect` is for :) Or if you need the action to go to a different page, use `PostBackUrl` or change the form action.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?  A quick search gives a number of similar error messages with proposed and accepted solutions.

[Server.Transfer throws Error executing child request. How to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361690/server-transfer-throws-error-executing-child-request-how-to-resolve)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1489436.aspx?Server+Transfer+Error+executing+child+request

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320439

You don't mention what you're transferring from, but I suspect `Response.Redirect` or `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` will be a better alternative for you.