# HttpContext.Server.Transfer to an IHttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, server.transfer

**Problem:**

I have an application defined within IIS, that points to a path containing a Web App. The Web App has a HttpHandler that handles all incoming requests, and forwards those requests onto other apps (also containing HttpHandlers) located in sub-directories, but not defined as applications in IIS. Essentially:

```
\
    \bin
        GatewayHandler.dll
        Application1.dll
    \Application1
        Application1Handler.ashx
    GatewayHandler.ashx
    web.config
```

The GatewayHandler, at the moment simply transfers the request to Application1 as follows:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Server.Transfer("Application1/Application1.ashx", true);
}
```

Yet, running this I get the error:

```
Error executing child request for Application1/Application1Handler.ashx.
```

I've looked high and low but from all my searching I cannot find why this would not work. I require all requests to always pass through GatewayHandler.ashx, so I don't wish to use a browser redirect.

**Edit:** Just to be clear, I'm *not* transferring from a HttpHandler to an aspx page which works no problem; I'm wanting to transfer from a HttpHandler to another HttpHandler in a sub-directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server.Transfer throws Error executing child request. How to resolve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361690/server-transfer-throws-error-executing-child-request-how-to-resolve)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Hi Patrick, thanks for pointing me in the direction of that QA, however I'm sorry but while it is close it isn't a duplicate. I'm not transferring from a HttpHandler to an aspx page, but a HttpHandler to another HttpHandler.

Comment: I think both are handled by the isapi asp.net handler. You can check by looking at the handlers' extensions in IIS.

Comment: The thing is, as my edit says, transferring to an aspx page works no problem, however I'm wanting to transfer to a HttpHandler which ISN'T working, yet the 'duplicate' question deals with an issue which is a non-issue for myself. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the handler itself doesn't thrown an exception?

Comment: It would appear not, the exception is thrown by the Transfer method.