# What can be the cause for "Error executing child request for /Page.aspx"?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm currently working on a ASP.NET project for a client and the client constantly receives this error. The problem is that when I run the project on my side, nothing happens. I searched and I've found a lot of solutions for this error, but I can't really try a solution till I manage to reproduce this on my side . 
The question is: what can be the cause for this?
I also checked https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320439/prb-error-executing-child-request-error-message-when-you-use-server-tr but it didn't really help me.
I'm a beginner in all of this so if someone could clearly explain to me why this is happening I'll be really grateful!

**EDIT**
This is the line of code that triggers the error:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Folder1/MyPage.aspx?xkey=" + logGuid.ToString()), _writer);
```

Comment: Can you share the code that triggers this error?

Comment: Also please share the path that the application is running in debug and the path the application runs during production

Comment: I edited my initial post. I don't have many details about the production...I just received this error and I have to reproduce it in my side

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361690/server-transfer-throws-error-executing-child-request-how-to-resolve ?

Comment: Yes I did, it  didn't really help me since I can't even reproduce the error .